# utilize require.js using data-main or require?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the following line in head.

```
<script data-main="{% static 'site_common/js/main.js' %}"  src='{% static "site_common/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" %}'></script>
```

main.js has

```
require(['site_common/js/config'], function() {
});
```

at the bottom of body, I have

```
 require(["site_common/js/config"], function () {

   require(['infrastructure'], function () {

   require([
       'content_tab/apps/content-tab-app',
     ], function(ContentTabApp) {

       var appOptions = {
         el: "#ann-content-app",
         contenttype: contenttype,
         threads_obj: threads_obj,
         thread_obj: thread_obj
       };

       var content_tab_App = new ContentTabApp(appOptions);

       Backbone.history.start({
         pushState: true,
         hashChange: false
       });


     });
   });

 });
```

I had the first line (with data-main) because I thought it was required but now I think it is superplous.

But then if I remove that line, how would the page know that it needs to download require.js itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on track. In this case what you are trying to do is load `require.js` script and pass `data-main` attribute pointing to entry-point of your application which is `main.js`

However, there are several other patterns you should take a look [at](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Patterns-for-separating-config-from-the-main-module)

```
<script data-main="{% static 'site_common/js/main.js' %}"  src='{% static "site_common/bower_components/requirejs/require.js" %}'></script>
```

...then in your `main.js`

```
require(["site_common/js/config"], // dependencies 1st loaded
function () { // callback after dependencies above have loaded successfully

   require(['infrastructure'], // this loads 2nd
   function () { // after second nested dependency loaded this callback will be executed

   require(['content_tab/apps/content-tab-app'], // this loads 3rd
    function(ContentTabApp) { // after third dependency has loaded this function will be called

       var appOptions = {
         el: "#ann-content-app",
         contenttype: contenttype,
         threads_obj: threads_obj,
         thread_obj: thread_obj
       };

       var content_tab_App = new ContentTabApp(appOptions);

       Backbone.history.start({
         pushState: true,
         hashChange: false
       });


     });
   });

 });
```